# how to pause Console window of Eclipse for Bosch XDK110

Tags: eclipse, segger-jlink, bosch-iot

I just got the XDK110.
I run an example program using the Eclipse IDE.
I want to pause the continuous printf outputs in the Console window.

I don't have a Jlink debugger yet.
I assume the IDE comes with NO debug capability whatsoever, which is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

To pause, I click the COM button in the XDK Devices window.
To continue, click again.